# Apache redirecting, I think?

Tags: apache-2.2

I am working to implement something called ProcessMaker.

It wants to have its files reside in /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html.

However my main site has its files in VirtualServer under /home/username/public_html/

How do I go about linking mainsite.com/processflow with the mainsite.com being under /home/username/public_html, and the /processflow actually residing in /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername ...

    DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html/

    Alias /processflow  /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html
    <Directory /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an alias to your VirtualHost as Dave says, but don't forget to also add a new directory directive to be able to access the file.

```
<Directory /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: @radius, i've added the <Directory /> syntax to my answer, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about virtual sites?

I know you can edit the apache2.conf or httpd.conf depending on your install and then see how the server handles hosts

here is an example

```
Listen 80

    NameVirtualHost *:80

    # Site 1 Comment

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName site1.intranet
      ServerAdmin administrator@whatever.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
    </VirtualHost>

    #  Site 2 Comment

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName site2.intranet
      ServerAdmin administrator@whatever.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
    </VirtualHost>
```

on this the DNS server routes traffic to any address with .intranet on port 80 to a server then the apache host file take the request to the right folder, note the part DocumentRoot

I think the newer apache has a file just for hosts and it is called by the main conf file

hope that helps